# Expectation of Documentation Reviews

Tags: discussion, documentation, review-queues

As somebody who regularly goes through review queues on the main Stack Overflow site, the introduction of reviewing Documentation edits has brought upon a conundrum for me.

**What are the expectations of reviews when going through this review queue?**

Originally, I went through the proposed changes in the specific topics that I am knowledgeable in, seeing which changes had correct code, first of all, and all the other requirements. However, this review queue has brought upon the question - what are we really meant to be reviewing. Obviously, if I get a proposed change about Java (for example) I am going to be reading the descriptions and the prose, rather than the code. However, is there a standard that has been set in stone? If not, could we lay a plan out for that?

Comment: There is also a discussion on [whether one should even review areas outside of one's expertise](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334357/documentation-review-may-be-encouraging-wrong-behavior)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

My chief opinion is that one should review the content to see if the example(s) are well written and fit in with the topic.  That is to say, you should review for things like:

- Correctness
- Completeness
- Plagiarism (make sure this isn't a thing)
- Spelling/Grammar
- Topicality (is a part of the topic)

I wouldn't say that there should be a set-in-stone standard, as we all have different review mentalities in general. However, the above bullet points as a rule of thumb should get you past some initial inertia.

Although to be fair, if you're *still* unclear as to how you can effectively review, it's better to not review anything than to make bad reviews.  Sit it out until you feel the role is clearer to you.

Comment: Indeed, we don't want any rubbish review decisions!

Comment: I would put 3 to the top. Plagiarism *is real*.

Comment: Completeness is good, but not a requirement. That's what improvement requests are for.