# Documentation Update, September 12th

Tags: discussion, documentation

This is the fourth post in our series of regular (roughly weekly) updates on the [Documentation Beta](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation). See also the [previous post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333420/documentation-update-august-29th) in the series.

### Shipped Changes

#### Proposed Changes Review Queue

[image: Review Queue]

[It finally happened](https://stackoverflow.com/review). We're still working through a bunch of little bugs, so keep the reports/upvotes coming. Looks like it's working for many people though, [see if you can spot when we soft-launched it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0pPLe.png).

[image: An item]

The old proposed changes interface has been replaced with a review queue. Old links still work, and proposed changes are still surfaced on tag dashboards.

There are also limited filtering options (just tags for now).

[image: Filtering in review queues]

#### Contributor Tracking For New Reputation

The new reputation system announced last time hasn't shipped yet (more on that below), but an integral part of it is running in the background: calculating the new contributor levels.

For any topic, you can go to `/documentation/contributors/topic/{id}` (and for any example, go to `/documentation/contributors/example/{id}`) and you'll see a page like this:

[image: Contributor breakdown]
<sub>[example link](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/topic/213)</sub>

This page was originally for debugging purposes (there are no links to it anywhere), but has been made publicly accessible to aid in bug reports and discussion in preparation for the new rep system.

### Planned Changes

We're going to be moving a little slower than usual in the coming week or so due to a number of team members being on vacation, however...

#### Focus Section

Focus is still coming - work can proceed now that the proposed changes review queue has shipped.

#### [Topic Outline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgFG7.png)

Likewise, still coming.

#### [Reputation Update](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334551/1983854)

**The reputation system update should ship this week**. As announced above, the contributor calculation portion is already live, and the awarding and recalcing portions are undergoing some final testing.

When the new system goes live there will be an announcement here on meta, and a topbar inbox notification for users whose rep was affected by the change.

#### More Proposed Change Review Queue Work

Things like audit tasks, an approve and edit option, a better display of conflicting changes, and so on will be coming down the pipe.

#### Per-Topic Discussion Section

We're in the very early stages of this, but we have been working on collecting the disparate commentary that relates to a topic and its examples (like comments on the initial request, improvement requests, and proposed changes) as well as providing a place to start new discussion.

There really isn't a perfect analog for this in Q&A (comments and chat are the closest, but both fail for different reasons). We're expecting to have a fair amount of proving out before we can get something built and shipped.

With a big ol' **this is a very early result of brainstorming** and not a final design, here's a look at our current best idea:

[image: Work in progress, seriously]

Don't get too hung up on anything in that mock-up; we're already working on a new revision. Expect to hear more in the future.

Comment: It's good to hear a discussion section is in the works. That will be very useful. It's also good to see something like the contributor page. I was having trouble finding time to figure up how much contributions I have where. And while it has issues, the review queue is a blessing! Each update is looking better and better to me. (And likely to several others.)

Comment: This per-Topic discussion… That looks MUUUUUCH better than what we have until now, no matter how WIP it currently is. Great :-) — But nevertheless, please first polish the review queue with audits etc. before going to other things.

Comment: @bwoebi audits and review queue polish will come before we do any development work on the discussion tab, but we'll be doing some UX / testing on mockups in tandem with the updated development work on the queue.

Comment: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329686/allow-for-area-51-like-mini-metas-per-documentation-tag

Comment: Thank you for this update. There's one thing I find very alarming - the fact there's no "tag score checking" when it comes to reviewers. In other words: IMHO, it is dangerous to let users review edits on topics they have no _SO-proven-knowledge_ in. As an example: I've just [made a change](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/94912) to some MATLAB-related doc, and it was approved by 3 users whose collective score in [tag:matlab] is **0**! What's the point of such a review? Solely the detection of vandalism?

Comment: Yet another review queue. What I don't understand from this is _who_ will do the reviews? Anyone with high enough rep like the regular review queues? Very bad idea. These will be very different from regular "site moderation" reviews. Documentation changes need to be reviewed to determine _the quality of the contents_, by people with deep technical knowledge of the topic. I really hope that the audit system checks for silver/gold tags or this is a complete fiasco. Generally, the complete lack of quality concerns is why the whole Documentation project is mostly big a fiasco so far.

Comment: @Dev-iL the lack of tag score and expertise is being [discussed on this post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334357/documentation-review-may-be-encouraging-wrong-behavior). I am also very concerned with this and think it will lead to massive robo-reviewers making SOD even worse then it is (i.e. what Lundin said)

Comment: Shameless plug: [User Script to show Contributor Breakdown links](http://stackapps.com/q/7040/28738) for those interested in an easy way to get these. and yes it's mine ..

Comment: Some progress. But the topics list gets longer and longer. Any ideas for the hierachical organization of the content?

Comment: Btw. It's a wonder there are still enough reviewers doing the work for free. After all, you don't create content, you don't get rep, you just do the dirty work, now in even one more review queue. Reviewers surely have earned all the praise of the world, but I'm actually a bit surprised there are still enough reviewers available.

Comment: I would like it if the reviewers of proposed changes had to have a bronze badge in the tag they're reviewing... I just saw an edit w/ an error get approved by three users with a combined rep of 3000 and a combined tag score of 19 (two of the users had a tag score of 0 in the tag).

Answer (score 26):

In terms of documentation review, I know there's a tag sort, but what if you required reviewers to have, for starters, at least one upvote for an answer in the tag they're reviewing in. Later, perhaps, it can be decided what the exact numbers should be, but that one upvote requirement will, I think, significantly narrow the field on who can review what and eliminate some of the problems. For example, I'd be able to review in the Python tag and the LaTeX tag, but not anything else.

Comment: I second this.  I know nothing about, say, [Django](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/django/topics), and haven't even looked at (let alone supplied an answer for) any questions tagged with it.  It's kinda dumb that I'm entirely capable of casting a vote as to whether an edit on a Django topic is good.

Comment: @JustinTime, exactly, and I hope others agree.

Comment: Linking here to my question addressing the same issue http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334357/documentation-review-may-be-encouraging-wrong-behavior (many good answers over there, some of them feel a lot like your proposal).