# Description Section in Documentation

Tags: feature-request, documentation

Something I noticed about documentation was that descriptions are often included in examples. It seems to me that there should be a section specifically for describing what something is. To me it seems to be most logical to put a text box in the edit panel where you can change the title and versions.

Comment: The Remarks section?

Comment: Or [the forthcoming "Focus section"](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334404/215552)

Comment: Remarks section is at the end, hardly suitable for this. "Focus Section" sounds like what I'm talking about, but I don't see any specific information on it

Comment: I'm pretty sure the [Focus section](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/331663/documentation-update-august-4th) will meet your need. It's coming, but has been overtake by more pressing features in the last few weeks.