# Documentation contributor chain on an Example is broken after a Topic move

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, documentation-examples

Strange journey to get here

1. I gave [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39835576/2370483), where I linked to a [docs example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/194/variables/2496/global-variable-best-practices) I wrote back before public beta
2. I got the Creditor badge for said link. But...

   > First citation of a **topic or example you haven't contributed to**, in an answer you posted
3. Er... I made the intial entry? So let's look at the contributor list at the end. Well, there's my avatar on the far right (hovering over it shows my name) 
   [image]
4. But there's that handy [Contributors tool from Sept 12](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334404/documentation-update-september-12th) now. Surely I'm in there? [Nope](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/topic/194)

So I got a badge I didn't deserve but I no longer count as having contributed to an Example I authored. As best as I can tell it [cuts off contributors after the Example was moved](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/revisions/194?exampleId=2496). And if we click the link to the previous entry next to the move entry... [hey, there I am](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/revisions/734?exampleId=2496). So it appears that miken32's move now makes him the major contributor and author of the Example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nice large stack of issues here, made it harder to figure out exactly what went wrong with this badge award.

First, a bug: the Creditor badge wasn't properly checking that the cited Documentation hadn't been edited by the citing user.  This has been fixed.

Second, a terminology change: Neither the Bluebook nor Creditor badge had their descriptions updated when the notion of major and minor contributors was introduced.  What they meant original was "cited documentation you (hadn't) edited".  Their descriptions have been updated.

Revision lists are scoped to topic (and optionally an example), to see the original contributor you have to click through the moved record [which shows you as the original creator of that example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/php/revisions/734?exampleId=2496).