# Documentation example contributor corruption results in reputation drop

Tags: bug, status-completed, documentation, reputation, docs-contributors

### Problem

The [contributor list for Creating and Initializing Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/404) has become corrupted.

Additional examples also known to be affected:

- [Getting started with Java Language - Creating your first Java program](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/378)
- [Linked List - Introduction to Linked Lists](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/10079)
- [Linked List - Singly Linked List](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/10190)
- [Declaration vs Definition - Understanding Declaration and Definition](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/10584)
- [Pointers - Common errors](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/4152)

### Investigation

Several minutes ago, I noticed my reputation had dropped by just under 2k. So, I started investigating. Based on these two Meta questions:

- [Reputation lost and there's no explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343442/reputation-lost-and-theres-no-explanation)
- [I've just lost 1760 reputation points without explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343559/ive-just-lost-1760-reputation-points-without-explanation) (definitely this issue)<sup>1</sup>.

I, initially, assumed it was from a documentation reputation recalculation. However, I have not [seen anything recently](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343091/documentation-update-february-6th?cb=1) that indicates that the definition of "major contributor" has changed, nor that the amount of reputation awarded per upvote has changed. The only recent issues affecting Documentation reputation I've seen were two bug fixes mentioned in [Adam Lear's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343443/3773011). Neither of those bugs should impact my reputation by more than a small amount. So, while my reputation certainly was recalculated, the expected amount of a "normal" Documentation reputation recalculation does not match the magnitude of the change in my reputation.

Investigating further, it appears that all of the [contributors](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/example/404) for [Creating and Initializing Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays/404/creating-and-initializing-arrays) have been forgotten / become corrupted. Currently, the contributors page for that example shows only one contributor, which is obviously erroneous:

[image: Erroneous contributors page]

I was considered to be a "major contributor" on "Creating and Initializing Arrays". I am still listed as a [major contributor to the topic "Arrays"](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/contributors/topic/99):

[image: Me as major contributor to Java - Arrays]

There has not been any [activity in the Java topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java?tab=activity) which would account for this issue (e.g. there is not a rollback to a pre-July 26 version).

Thus, it appears the contributor list for "Creating and Initializing Arrays" has become corrupted, but the contributor list for the topic: [Java - Arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/99/arrays) remains accurate (as far as I looked).

As verification, I searched through my reputation history. Doing so shows my current reputation is consistent with what it would be if I was not a contributor to "Creating and Initializing Arrays" (i.e. no reputation is listed for that example, but reputation from other Documentation examples is shown). In other words, the corruption of the contributor list for that example is consistent with the effect I am seeing on my reputation.

Prompted by a [note in chat by PetterFriberg](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/35622744#35622744), the additional affected examples were found by looking through the contributions of the user that remains listed in the contribution lists for the affected examples.<sup>2</sup>

###Contributor list corruption may contribute to other reported reputation losses

It is near certain that other people are affected by the corruption of the contributor list for the above Documentation example. In addition, if this can happen to the contributor list for one example, it may have happened to other examples. Whatever caused this corruption may have also corrupted other examples.  The corruption of the contributor list for other examples may be contributing to the various recent reported reputation drops (see links at the top of this question for a couple).

---

1. [Malt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3199595/malt) made an [edit to the Creating and Initializing Arrays example](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/review/changes/59738?filter-tags=java) and ["[java] Arrays" is listed in their contributions, but not the specific example](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3199595/malt?tab=documentation&sort=contributions).  This issue is certainly what caused their reputation loss. I [left them a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343559/ive-just-lost-1760-reputation-points-without-explanation#comment446649_343559) explaining and pointing here.
2. I'm not explicitly mentioning the user here because the problem is unlikely to be a result of them manipulating the SO UI. In other words, I'm trying to avoid "calling them out" for something that is nearly certain to not be their fault. There are other Documentation edits by this user to examples for which they are the only contributor.

<sup>Note: This question is reporting a bug, not a concern about lost reputation. I'm not concerned about losing the reputation points; overall, I have negative feelings about gaining reputation from Documentation. As a side benefit to this bug, I had been wondering how much reputation I had gained, in total, from that *one* Documentation edit. Now I know: just under 2k.</sup>

Comment: This is indeed curious.  I admit, playing Devil's Advocate, I'm a bit torn on the matter.  If it's corrupted it should be fixed, but I rather do like the fact that a lot of people that gained a lot of reputation from a rather menial piece of documentation don't have it anymore...

Comment: @Makoto, I'm torn too. Bug➞fix it. Too much reputation gained➞leave this one. Realizing, in July, that I was likely to end up with a huge amount of reputation from such a small contribution to SO significantly reduced my motivation to contribute more substantially to Documentation and, to an extent, to SO generally. I've, many times, wished I could disassociate myself from the edit I made to that example so I don't get the rep. Compare my rep from edits: 1 edit on Documentation = 2k rep (so far); 900+ edits on SO = 70 rep. So much rep from Docs cheapens the rep I get for answering questions.

Comment: @Makyen actually, I got 1K rep from my edits on SO. You can get a lot, it turns out, you just need to be <2K, or do tag wiki edits.

Comment: So _that's_ where those 25 rep went that I still had last week.

Comment: @StephenLeppik, It's not that one *can't* get rep for non-Docs edits. Rep for edits just *isn't* what motivates *me*. But, the *huge* disparity between rep earned on Docs vs. the level of contribution does demotivate *me* from making contributions. The huge amount of rep I've earned, for what I consider to be a minor Docs improvement, makes me *feel* my other contributions to SO (i.e. answers) are being belittled. If there was no rep gained, or just the single +2, for Docs edits, I would have contributed *significantly* more to Docs. That's just the way it is *for me*, because of how *I feel*.

Comment: @Makoto The bug and reputation are two separate issues. The bug has to be fixed, and steps should be taken to make sure that such problems are easier to identify. The question of  "a menial piece" resulting in a large reputation gain is a question of general SO policy. As a rule of thumb the reputation system puts content popularity above all else. How does the reputation gain from a piece of documentation any different from the gain from answers such as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/477819/3199595)? Reputation hardly ever reflects effort or quality in general, not just with documentation.

Comment: @Malt:  I'm a little concerned that you missed my half-sarcasm there.  I'm well aware that if this is a bug that it needs to be fixed, but given that Java is so extensively and well-documented, the fact that it's on Documentation has [always rubbed me the wrong way](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334291/1079354).

Comment: @Makoto Your point wasn't missed, and I agree that we, as a community, tend to document the wrong things by documenting the easy and the obvious before all else just just because it's easy. I'm just making the point that this is not in any way different than the rest of SO. The accessible, the easy, and the popular, is (almost) always answered first, and is rewarded with more reputation than the hard, the complex, and the esoteric.

Comment: " 1 edit on Documentation = 2k rep (so far); 900+ edits on SO = 70 rep." -- Or, at the risk of stating the obvious: 1 edit on Documentation ~ 1 answer with **200** upvotes. That's a heck of a lot of rep...

Comment: @Makyen [I predicted the rep inflation.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/329459/329513#comment373405_329513) It is happening. Wake up people!

Comment: Oh so there is my lost 2k.

Comment: Woof. I'm not at a spot right now where I can dig in, but one of us on the Docs team will investigate this ASAP on Monday.

Comment: So that's where my 200 rep went.  @Makoto I fully agree, there probably shouldn't be a Java section at all.  In fact I'm still trying to figure out what Documentation is for, other than a different way to get eyeballs for advertising dollars.

Comment: It's a two faced dragon, this bug. On one hand, it's a pretty serious bug and should be corrected, on the other hand, it finally put some brakes on the documentation gravy train.

Comment: @totymedli [Same](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/328444/5529417).

Comment: Sounds similar to a [bug I found a while back](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/335677/documentation-contributor-chain-on-an-example-is-broken-after-a-topic-move), except mine was more focused on an incorrect badge. I suspect the contributors list has some hidden gotchas

Comment: Working on this now.

Comment: Also, I seem to have gained (around) 2k rep after the account merge (not from the old account). I still keep receiving extra rep everyday because of docs even though I shouldn't get it. Looks like a rep calc will also be needed for me @AdamLear. Sorry, I didn't report this earlier; I'm extremely busy with school right now.

Comment: I think I found the cause of the missing contributors - working on a solution now.

Comment: This appears to be fixed: the contributor lists have been fixed, and a rep recalc will restore the lost rep.

Comment: @RamenChef, Yes, the contributor lists have been restored. I've been gaining rep from upvotes on the Java - Arrays example from about 16:19 UTC. However, that does not mean the bug which caused the corruption has been corrected. Hopefully it has. I've been waiting for some official word. The original recalculations spanned, at least, 34 hours. I assume it may take some time for new recalculations to correct the issue for all those affected (e.g. Malt's rep has returned, but mine...returned between when I started writing this comment and when I finished, and is still moving through the system).

Comment: Right - there's still a bug floating around that can cause contributors to be incorrectly removed.  Trying to get a repro and some tests.

Answer (score 9):

Alright, I think I've patched everything up, rebuilt all the contributors, and recalc'ed the rep of all affected users.

Backstory: for reputation calculation purposes, we have a "Contributors" table that makes it easy to determine both when a user edited a topic/example and how large their contribution was.  It's all denormalized data, built from the raw topic/example history records, so it can become incorrect over time if we have bugs.

The major bug occurred when a contributing user was merged with another user (this can be a [self-service process or even automatic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170073/3)).  During a merge, only that user's contributions were taken into account when rebuilding contributors on the topics/examples that user worked on.  This meant all other users' contributions were erased :(

There were a few other smaller bugs, mostly around the first contributions a topic/example had, which have now been fixed.

This took a bit longer than expected, as I needed to build up some unit test helpers/tooling and I was out for a week with the flu.  Good news is new bugs (and there probably will be, it's complex) should get fixed faster :)

Comment: So is this Documented now? ;)

Comment: Nice work. I'm glad to hear it's resolved.

Comment: My reputation dropped last month and jumped back up now. Good to know that somebody is working on this

Comment: My reputation points are not being updated on stackoverflow