# Point deduction after user deletion is wrongly displayed

Tags: bug, reputation, deleted-users

From my point history:

```
-9    Feb 6
-10 18:32   removed User was removed (learn more)
+1  15:15   upvote  Exiting Vim
```

Prior to that day I was at 7k points, after the deletion 30 points were removed from my account and I had about 6970.

Is that bug already known? Could not find something here on meta.
This is not related to the stackoverflow documentation area.

Comment: So you're saying you lost more reputation than your history indicates?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Documentation example contributor corruption results in reputation drop](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343581/documentation-example-contributor-corruption-results-in-reputation-drop)

Comment: @Bart : exactly.