# Why doesn't the OP earn any reputation when their discussion becomes upvoted?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, discussions-space

People on SE earn reputation when their answer gets upvoted/accepted. But why doesn't the OP earn any reputation when their discussion becomes upvoted?

Comment: Rep is not gained or lost on discussions

Comment: @Fastnlight yes, but actually why?

Comment: Discussions are still in a experimental / beta phase, the feature not being tied to reputation is deliberate.

Comment: Well received content under “discussions” correlates very little with the type of content that’s considered “good” in the real site. Inflating reputation because activity there would be a disservice to the reputation system (without discounting that exactly that could happen in the future, once out of beta)

Comment: It’d be kinda silly for something that useless to provide similar rep gain to producing valuable content.

Comment: @Kastet6398 - Discussions are not questions.  If a discussion answers a question it probably should have been a question.

Comment: Man, you should have been around for the debacle that was reputation in Documentation.

Comment: Yeah, I'm still embarrassed over the reputation I earned from Documentation for what was, while actually helpful edits/content, dramatically disproportionate rep gain compared to the effort. If SE/SO started giving reputation for discussions, then I'd probably think it was time to leave the site entirely.

Comment: @Makyen I mean it was a lot of work for what, like a couple hundred rep? It was problematic, but I don't think it was that embarrassing. At least not as embarrassing as SO's abandonment of it.

Comment: @TylerH I got a couple *thousand* rep from a single edit on Documentation. Once I realized, after I'd edited, that I was going to end up with so much reputation from it, I really wished I'd created an alternate account to perform the edit, so the reputation wasn't gained by my main account. For more information, see my question: "[Documentation example contributor corruption results in reputation drop](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343581/3773011)" and my comments there.

Comment: @Makyen oh, yikes

Comment: In the general case of the why when it comes to anything on Stack Overflow, try to come up with repercussions in the hypothetical case where it would exist. In general it is not too hard to come up with a couple yourself and that should already answer "why". How can it be abused? Is there a butterfly effect? Those kind of things. Granted, it is important to have a good grasp of what Stack Overflow's goal is to do that effectively. Or original goal, because the existence of discussions is a signal that things are changing. They've gone and added Reddit to the site, quite a milestone.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From the Help Center's [*What is Reputation?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) page:

> Reputation is a rough measurement of how much the community trusts you; it is earned by convincing your peers that you know what you’re talking about.

Discussions are open-ended, not *really* moderated, and typically stretch into matters of opinion. Discussions don't provide any direct value to the "focused Q&A" aspect that Stack Overflow is known for/designed to achieve, so they don't earn any reputation for the person who starts one.

Comment: "not *really* moderated" -____-